# Cannot post a file using cURL

Tags: php, curl

The scenario is to send a file from a PHP application in server1 (local server) to a C#.net application in server2.

While sending a file using a simple HTML form, the destination server receives it with no problem.

While sending that file using cURL I get error 500 from destination server
Note that I don't have access to the destination server and its admin is sure that everything is okay because of the the successful submission of HTML form.

Here is my code to post file:

```
$filedata = $fileName; // Absolute path of the file ==> 'D:\wamp\www\my_project\upload\image\201401070657414.jpg'
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); 
$postfields = array("filedata" => "@$filedata", "filename" => $fileName);
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://server2/postphoto.aspx', //500
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
    CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => filesize($filedata),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

And curl_getinfo($ch) returns:

```
array (size=26)
  'url' => string 'http://server2/postphoto.aspx' (length=41)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=utf-8' (length=24)
  'http_code' => int 500
  'header_size' => int 265
  'request_size' => int 203
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 0.032
  'namelookup_time' => float 0
  'connect_time' => float 0
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0
  'size_upload' => float 28998
  'size_download' => float 7127
  'speed_download' => float 222718
  'speed_upload' => float 906187
  'download_content_length' => float 7127
  'upload_content_length' => float 28998
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.016
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  ...
```

what is wrong with my code?

The variable $response shows:

```
string 'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 08:31:54 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 6

nofile' (length=249)
```

Content-Type rturns text/html while I have already set it to multipart/form-data in my header.

The following is the Asp.net code on server2:

```
    if (Request.Files.Count == 0)
    {
        Response.Write("nofile");
        return;
    }
    System.Web.HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[0];

    System.IO.Stream streamObj = file.InputStream;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
    streamObj.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    streamObj.Close();
    streamObj = null;


    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("d:\\photo\\" + file.FileName, buffer);
```

Comment: you should post the `c#` code.

Comment: I have also tested it with php and got the same error.

Comment: show us the HTML source for the "simple html form" that works with a browser

Comment: look at the answers bellow. I have written what is posted by cURL. it sounds that it is not valid. I guess there might be a problem with $filedata source.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a variable to curl_exec($ch); like so `$response = curl_exec($ch);` and do a var_dump `var_dump($response)`. Show us what is the response from the server.

Comment: string 'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 08:26:38 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 6

nofile' (length=249)

Comment: The result you posted is truncated. Try doing an echo instead.

Comment: Are you using a relative path in your filename? Try changing it with absolute path. Also try passing the filename to file_exists() function and see if the file really exists.

Comment: Yes I use absolute path and file_exists() function returns true.

Comment: Try using an HTML form with a file input field and submit the form to the server. See if it that would work.

Comment: It is not the thing I am looking for. I wouldn't go through with above solution if I wanted to use an html form. The goal is to automate posting a bunch of files which has been placed in a specified folder to the second server

Comment: I know. I just want you to test if your VB.NET codes do work.

Answer (score 0):

I think `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE` is for PUT requests only. Instead, explicitly set POST:

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => POST
CURLOPT_POST          => true
```

I also suggest `"filedata" => "@" . $filedata` - not sure either.

Here is something wrong:

```
$filedata = $fileName; // Absolute path of the file
```

They can't be the same, one contains the full absolute path to the file, likely to be `/tmp/phpcpjNeQ`, the other contains the filename without path `test_file.csv`.

To verify if your local file is accessable, use `fopen()`.

```
assert(is_resource(fopen($filedata, 'r')));
```

Comment: assert function returns true

Comment: $filedata is like this: 'D:\wamp\www\my_project\upload\image\201401070657414.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

Trying to handle the request using php gives a file array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [filedata] => Array
        (
            [name] => 201401070657414.jpg
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\php519A.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 28619
        )

)
```

so what is the mistake here!?

Answer (score -1):

This works, change the variables accordingly to your needs:

```
<?php   
        $post_data['content']  = "@/c:/xampp/htdocs/site/a.doc";
        $post_data['filename'] = "a.doc";

        foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value)
        {
            $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
        }

        $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);



    //create cURL connection
$curl_connection =  curl_init('https://yoururl.com/form.php');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

echo $result;

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);

?>
```

For more info check this [link](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html)

Comment: This is a simple copy&paste from google without explanation, without verification.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, who told you that I haven't tested the code ? I've done it and guess what ? it works.

Comment: Still, you don't explain **why** your code works, but the OP's doesnt.